# Reload Data in ListView When Change Orientation

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-layout

I have a listview that displays categories from my server. It works fine but when i change orientation it reloads it...

What should I do to avoid reloads ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could prevent this by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in AndroidManifest file.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075540/android-application-restarts-on-orientation-change/4075582#4075582) out.